# Sed expression with double s

Tags: sed

Please explane sed expression in:

```
PACKAGE=`grep package $MANIFEST_FILE | sed 's/.*package="//;s/".*//'`
```

I cannot understand this part:

```
//;s/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in fact two sed substitutions commands, separated by `;` :

```
s/.*package="//  # replace anything on the line before 'package=' string + string
s/".*//'`        # replace " and all the rest of the line after this character
```